# Changing display name on Meta.SO does not change it on Meta chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

Changing your display name on Meta.SO does not change it on Meta's chat area.

At first, I thought it was simply because I was the last person to post in the Gaming Recommendations chatroom, but even my chat profile lists my old display name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will change within an hour. If you feel strongly about having it change immediately, you can ask a moderator (anyone with a blue username) to refresh your profile. I've done this in your case now.

Comment: Ooh, that's nice. It does update now. Question, though, does the `/logout` option that used to be cited during the earlier stages no longer work?

Comment: @Grace Yeah, that still works. But consider it an undocumented workaround :)

Comment: `/logout` doesn't seem to work any more. Upon clicking the "log out" button, I simply get redirected back to `/` and I remain logged in.