# Username changes not propagated to chat on change

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, display-names

I've changed my name on the stackexchange network on all my accounts a long time ago to user1066946. Just now I joined the Skeptics chat, I can't recall if I've been in a chatroom since my name change but for some reason my old username, and old icon were displayed, but when I hovered over my account it displayed the right "newer" information again.

---

[image]:

---

I thought i'd try and see if this was the case in all chatrooms, so I went to this site's chat, and the website was using the correct name and icon again.

---

[image]

---

When I now rejoin the Skeptics chatroom it also displays the correct information, this only seems to have happened once.

For the record I also login using different OpenId Google accounts, all linked to the same stackexchange account.

Comment: Note that in the meantime, my username once again is `Philipp`, at the time of writing the question though - it was `user1066946`. :-)

Comment: Ten years later, still broken.

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

1. When you change your name on the main site, it [may take a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63997/changing-display-name-on-meta-so-does-not-change-it-on-meta-chat) until it reflects in chat.
2. When chat notices a name (or avatar) change, it used to be the case that this wasn't reflected in the live chat until you reloaded the page. This has been annoying me forever, and I could really hit myself not fixing this earlier. Alas, I've finally done this yesterday. In most cases, the change will appear in the live chat immediately; in all cases it will appear eventually. This includes a client-side change, so it's only true for chat pages that were loaded after this change went into effect.

I'll mark this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) because of 2.